# Configuration files between different languages

Tags: c#, c++, configuration-files

What would be the best way to implement a configuration file between c# and c++? It has not to be readable by humans.

I thougt about XML or JSON, are there easier or more efficient ways to do it?

Comment: Describe 'better'. You'll see that this is an abstract term and is primarily opinion based.

Comment: What are you unhappy with regarding XML and JSON? Are you experiencing ease-of-use or efficiency problems?

Comment: Not human readable? SQLite?

Comment: You can simply use some hash map to store configuration in some simple text file, without imply some concepts of database structure. You can also encrypt values for key set, or could even encrypt all content.

Comment: Do you mean you want it to be difficult for humans to read? or do you mean you don't care whether or not it is easy for humans to read?

Comment: Working on Windows, how about the good old ".ini" ?

Comment: XML and JSON will be readable by humans. So will ini files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best way", its fully up to you.

If you think XML (clean&stable) is to hard or the implementation is to big, you could also use easy formats like CSV where you would have to know what Information is on which place:

```
C:\Userspath;MyFavouriteColor;MyWindowSize;etc.
```

I think for you it would be good to create an own format.
You have multiple ways to format your data:

- Seperate it by characters
- Order it by numbers
- Create a tree structure (would be like XML)

Some more Examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll create my own format with encoding.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the Answer-marking and good luck :)